# How to better reword this sentence? (SAT Writing question)

Tags: grammaticality

The security office recommends that, when asked to provide a computer password, **do not choose** any string of letters that can be found in a dictionary.

- a) do not choose *(incorrect, I think this would make the sentence a run-on)*
- b) not to choose *(what I had thought was correct because "The security office recommends not to choose any string of letter that can be found in a dictionary." sounds correct to me)*
- c) not choosing *(incorrect, doesn't "sound" right)*
- d) you not choose *(includes the pronoun "you," so I had automatically ruled this option out)*
- e) your choice should not be *(too wordy)*

But the correct answer had turn out to be option d. Please explain why, in the end, d is the correct answer?

Comment: Delete the part between commas.  Then the sentence reads wrong.  "...recommends that do not choose...".  The sentence "... recommends that you [do] not choose" reads correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew is correct. They placed an adverbial phrase between the transitive verb and the direct object (phrase). I believe that you omitted the word *that*, following *recommends*, when choosing your answer, which led you to believe that option B was correct. It is an easy mistake to make if you are not paying close attention.